# I flagged a "What is a good first [language] program to build" question as "primarily opinion-based" but it was declined. Why?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic, declined-flags

I flagged this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220920/what-is-a-good-first-c-app-to-build-besides-hello-world as "**primarily opinion-based**" but my flag was declined (no specific reason was given).

I know this kind of question is useful, but it's not a good fit for SO's Q&A format.

What say you, O' secret council?

Comment: It was declined by Community♦ - not 100% sure what that actually means though in the new close vote world order. I think it might be related to the 3 "leave opens" at: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2591156.

Comment: @Doorknob: No, if you cannot yet *vote* to close, you can *flag* to close. Same option structure. You need [3k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to VTC, the OP has 2.7k.

Comment: @Martijn Oh! I've forgotten you can do that :P

Comment: @Flexo: Blergh, those reviewers ought to be be taught about community standards.

Comment: @Flexo The timestamps seems to agree. So if everyone voted "Leave Open" in response to your flag, it'll show as "declined"?

Comment: Why does this need to be closed as 'no longer reproduceable'? Has the functionality changed where such flags are no longer marked as declined by Community?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If my understanding of the new flagging/closing system is correct your flag caused the question to be shown in the close votes /review queue.

The question was shown to 3 people. [All 3 said "leave open"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2591156). Looking at the timestamps it seems that when the third "leave open" vote was cast that was enough for 
Community♦ diamond to act on the flags and decline them. (The timestamp of the final vote exactly coincides with the timestamp of the decline). The entire process was handled by users in the community.

I disagreed with the flag being declined (and so did one other user) so I've now taken action on this.

Comment: I disagree too. I would have closevoted if it wasn't already close- I mean, on hold. (+1)

Comment: Regarding "*If my understanding of the new flagging/closing system is correct your flag caused the question to be shown in the close votes /review queue*", this behavior has only been introduced in the recent (June) Closure-related revamp? I thought it has always been the case (that certain flagged posts go to Close Votes queue)?

Comment: The change is that they no longer get shown to diamond mods at all. I think it's also new that they get declined automatically rather than by a mod, but I'm not totally sure on that, since I never normally see them as either a mod or a user.